# using google maps api on android 2.1(api 7)

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know how to use google map api in my application.I have found google add on libraies for android 2.1 which contains maps.jar in it.But google says maps api is supported in android 2.2+.So I want to know if I can use maps api or not.If yes then please provide me any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Google Maps Android API v2 on 2.1.

You can:

1. continue to use Google Maps Android API v1 (if you have a key for old maps - you cannot request new keys)
2. use Google Maps API v3 - embed javascript API in WebView
3. run Google Maps application via Intent
4. Use other maps providers, like [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't personally tried for my self, if they say it doesn't work I would trust what they're saying.

I believe it's due to the [lack of support for OpenGl 2.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/XpP2CN2qELE) on Eclair

But just for your consideration, there are virtually no 2.1 devices anymore. You can safely set your app to be 2.2+ and you won't be losing any potential users.
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html